# Can I add custom metadata to files?

Tags: box-api

I am interested in developing an enterprise app for Box.com . I would like to be able to categorize documents by additional metadata, for example a client id.

Is there any way to do this within the Box API v2? Could this be done with tags? (I can't find much about tags in the API Documentation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tags seem like a reasonable solution for this. However, they haven't yet been released in v2 but will be eventually. You can probably try using the v1 tags methods in the interim.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because they are only mentioned once in the v2 API.